# Why I get two different appearances between w3schools and jsFiddle using the same code about Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I have wanted to ask question about `Bootstrap nav` and write some code in jsFiddle to make question more clearer, but I found I can not finish it in jsFiddle, because when I used the same code from `w3schools` in Fiddle I got a unsatisfied appearance:
such as [W3schools's example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_case_navbar&stacked=h) and http://jsfiddle.net/69a2q5m3/

I analysed it simply, I thought the different versions of `jQuery and BootStrap` impact the result, but after I used `External Resources` the result did not change.

What should I do if I want to get the same appearance as the `w3schools`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/69a2q5m3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the viewport size the layout seems to be different on both sites. Both of them use iframe to display the output, So set the size of result window same size in both the websites and you will see the same result.

Comment: When I set both body's width to `200px`, I really got the same appearances , but If setting `500px`, in jsFiddle `WebSiteName` and `Home, page 1, page 2 and page3` are also placed in two lines, and in `W3schools` they are in same line like before

Comment: bootstrap uses media query's to style , so just resize the box in jsfiddle and the output will be same

Comment: “the box” you said means `body` or other things such as `div`?

Comment: nope the output box , the one on the bottom right in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Remove the css file,jsfidle provides it by `default` : [see](http://jsfiddle.net/69a2q5m3/1/)

Comment: you where using an external css that modified the default bootstrap css that is why the text and the button differ from the w3 site